# 3 picture slide show javascript code, what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, function, slideshow, slide

Here is my current code, it does not work how i would like it to tho. I want it to cycle 3 pictures in a slide show with a javascript code. I have the text/javascript file made and the html written, the problem is in here, not in the other files.

```
var step=1;
    function slideit()
    {
        document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
        if(step<2)
            step++;

        setTimeout("slideit()",2500);

        else if(step<3)
            step++;

        setTimeout("slideit()",2500);

        else
            step=1;

    }
    slideit();
```

All help is appreciated!

Comment: If either of our answers helped you solve your problem, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Your `if/else` statements are incorrect.

You need to place braces `{}` around the code after the if and before the else.

Another way of writing it could be:

```
var step = 1;
function slideit()
{
    document.getElementById("imageId").src = eval("image" + step + ".jpg");
    if ( step < 3 ) step++;
    else step = 1;
    setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And more, if you wish to slide each one you should use setInterval instead of setTimeout because setTimeout will sum the total timeouts and does a task only a single time

Answer (score 0):

This should work a bit better for you, and is easier to read.

```
var step=1;
function slideit()
{
   document.getElementById("imageId").src = eval("image" + step + ".jpg");
   if(step<3)
       step++;
   else
        step=1;
   setTimeout(slideit, 2500);
}
slideit();
```

Or if you want to go with @Besatamin's answer:

```
var step=1;
function slideit()
{
   document.getElementById("imageId").src = eval("image" + step + ".jpg");
   if(step<3)
       step++;
   else
        step=1;
}
var sliderIntervalId = setInterval(slideit, 2500);
```

You can then later stop it by:

```
clearInterval(sliderIntervalId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've a similar solution as some of the already answered ones. Please do have a look. It worked for me in safari on mac.

I've an images folder which has 3 images viz. 1.jpg, 2.jpg and 3.jpg. You can use your own images and run the script. I feel it works.

The html code is `<img name="slide" />`

```
var step=1;
function slideit(){
document.images.slide.src = "images/"+step+".jpg";
if(step<3)
    step++;
else
    step=1;

setTimeout("slideit()",1000);   
}
slideit();
```